# How to define transparent colors in latex?

Tags: color

I just can define white color using below tex code, how can I define transparent color in latex?

```
\definecolor{white}{rgb}{1,1,1}
```

Comment: *Transparent color* doesn't mean anything. You can define a certain level of opacity (between 0 and 1) for your objects, like `\fill[blue, opacity=0.5] (0,0) circle (4cm);`. And you don't have to define `white`, it's already done.

Comment: if the command is \filldraw[white][odd even rule], how can l make opacity is 1.

Comment: Opacity default value is one, which means totally opaque.